# Android Gradle: Mixing Versions leads to runtime crashes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am integrating Firebase into my application. A couple of errors pop up in the gradle file when I added the line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Attaching the screenshot of the error:
[image]

The latest version of com.google.android.gms:play-services is 15.0.1.

How to resolve this?

I know downgrading everything to 15.0.1 may solve the error situation. But I don't want to downgrade the libraries.

Comment: Can api post all your dependencies? I think you could exclude the nested dependency `com.goolge.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1` if you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the "lowest common denominator", which in your case is `version 15.0.1` for all your libraries that currently have `version 16.0.0` listed under your `dependencies`.